# parte final de una QUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Estoy finalizando una query que me han pedido pero no consigo terminarla, la estructura de las tablas es la siguiente:

**child**

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD(
child_id SMALLINT,
child_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(255),
city VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT PK_CHILD PRIMARY KEY(child_id)
```

**Sibling**

```
CREATE TABLE SIBLING(
child_id1 SMALLINT,
child_id2 SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_SIBLING PRIMARY KEY(child_id1, child_id2),
CONSTRAINT CHILD1_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id1) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD2_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id2) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);
```

**letter**

```
CREATE TABLE LETTER(
letter_id SMALLINT,
arrival_date DATE NOT NULL,
number_toys INTEGER NOT NULL,
delivery_mode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
child_id SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_LETTER PRIMARY KEY(letter_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);
```

**wished_toy**

```
 CREATE TABLE WISHED_TOY(
 letter_id SMALLINT,
 toy_id SMALLINT,
 CONSTRAINT PK_WISHED_TOY PRIMARY KEY(letter_id, toy_id),
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (letter_id) REFERENCES LETTER(letter_id)
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (toy_id) REFERENCES TOY(toy_id)
 );
```

**toy**

```
CREATE TABLE TOY(
toy_id SMALLINT,
toy_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL NOT NULL,
toy_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_TOY PRIMARY KEY(toy_id),
);
```

Me piden que haga una query que contenga la lista de niños(Child) que han pedido un juguete pedido también por uno de sus hermanos (Sibling).En concreto se quiere el identificador del niño child_id,el nombre child_name y su fecha de nacimiento birth_date.

Tengo esta parte ya de la query echa,pero algo me falla,no se como comparar los juguetes que ha pedido cada niño...

```
SELECT ch.child_id,ch.child_name,ch.birth_date
FROM child ch 
right outer join sibling si ON ch.child_id= SI.child_id1
left outer join letter l 
on ch.child_id=l.child_id
left outer join wished_toy wt on l.letter_id=wt.letter_id
```

Comment: Es esta una base de datos de producción?, porque la verdad me parece que la tabla `sibling` está mal diseñada

Comment: Es tal cual me la han pasado, yo pensé lo mismo pero así es, por eso tanta duda @Lamak

Comment: podes armar un fiddle con esto y ejemplos? creo que se podria aplicar una solucion loca para resolverlo, que vaya del juguete al niño en lugar del niño al juguete. algo asi como buscar todos los juguetes que se repiten, ubicar los niños, ubicar si existen en la tabla hermanos y listo.

Comment: Disculpa, no te entendí la solución que propones ¿Puedes ponerla en forma de Query si me haces el favor? @gbianchi

Comment: no, porque necesitaria las tablas.. por eso te pedi un fiddle.. no se si va a funcionar, es una idea, capaz terminando siendo algo todavia mas complicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitaria un esquema de prueba y datos, pero creo que asi deberias poder resolverlo (con las disculpas del caso, estoy trabajando en el aire, y mas disculpas puede que la sintaxis en postgress sea algo diferente)

```
TABLA JUGUETES_PEDIDOS:
select toy_id, count(*) as cuenta from WISHED_TOY group by toy_id  (devuelve la cuenta de juguetes) 

TABLA CARTAS_JUGUETES:
SELECT letter_id, toy_id from WISHED_TOY where toy_id IN (SELECT * FROM JUGUETES_PEDIDOS WHERE cuenta > 1) (o se podia usar un having en la consulta anterior, devuelve las cartas que en las cuales se repiten juguetes)

TABLA NIÑOS_JUGUETES:
SELECT CHILD_ID, toy_id  
FROM 
   LETTER l inner join CARTAS_JUGUETES c on l.letter_id = c.letter_id 
(Encuentro todos los niños que pidieron juguetes, y que juguete)

TABLA CRUZADA_DE_JUGUETES:
SELECT N1.toy_id, N1.CHILD_ID child_id1, N2.CHILD_ID child_id2 FROM NIÑOS_JUGUETES N1 INNER JOIN NIÑOS_JUGUETES N2 ON N1.toy_id = N2.toy_id  
(CREA UNA TABLA PARECIDA A SIBLING.. OJO VA A REPETIR REGISTROS PARA EL NIÑO CONSIGO MISMO)

TABLA FINAL:
SELECT * FROM CRUZADA_DE_JUGUETES c INNER JOIN Sibling s ON c.child_id1 = s.child_id1 and c.child_id2 = s.child_id2
```

Esto deberia dar como resultado, una tabla donde los niños hayan pedido el mismo regalo.. pero sin datos es una linda solucion teorica... que se puede escribir en un solo query, con mucho cuidado.